# Test screen on the android system

Tags: android, arm, screen, device

I got an `android 4.2.2` running on the my device, based on the variscite var-som-om44. I need to test my screen now: I put the right timings in the `/sys/devices/platform/omapdss/display0/timings` and it seems to be initialised, but it's black and nothing's there.

Question: How can I test my screen? How can I run some app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the overlay0 was switched off, then I turned it on with

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/omapdss/overlay0/enabled
```

display starts to work.